# Number of layers of the model

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm training a CNN. For reporting purposes, I want to find out the number of layers my model has.

From what I see in the code below, I have a total of 6 layers, layer1, layer2, conv2_drop, fc1, fc2, fc3. Am I right?

```
Net(
  (layer1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 10, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
    (1): BatchNorm2d(10, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (2): ReLU()
    (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (4): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
  )
  (layer2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
    (1): BatchNorm2d(20, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (2): ReLU()
    (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (4): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
  )
  (conv2_drop): Dropout2d(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=250, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=250, out_features=50, bias=True)
  (fc3): Linear(in_features=50, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

Does my NN have 6 layers, or layer1 and layer2 themselves add 4 more each? That would be 14 layers total?

Comment: one weakness of stackoverflow is it has a brittle way of putting into distinct silo various flavors of questions ... my guess that is why the down vote ... you might get better traction posting CNN questions at a sibling forum however I personally like these questions to get asked here on SO ...  take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what one would consider a layer (is `flattening` a layer or just an operation? What if it's implemented as `torch.nn.Module`?). Neural networks are, in essence, graphs performing operations, layers are a helpful abstraction which helps us reason about them.

In PyTorch, IMO, it would be a single instance of `torch.nn.Module`, so in this case it would be `14`. Even more so, `BatchNorm` is considered a layer universally and for ease I would consider others (`ReLU`, `MaxPool2d`, `Dropout`) as ones as well.

`layer1` and `layer2` is more of a block (stack of layers) in this case. Still your `fc1`, `fc2` and `fc3` should be IMO (notice I've used it again) coded as another `block` (wrapped in `torch.nn.Seqeuntial` probably).